# Install g++ from source in Fedora 26

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, fedora

I am trying to install a c++ compiler on a IBM Power7 with Fedora 26.
In /usr/bin it is installed gcc `[(GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)]` but it has not the c++ compiler (I tried `gcc -lstdc++` but the result is: `

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

I **do not have sudo rights** so I have to install everything from source.
I was able to install:

- Zlib
- Perl
- Curl
- Git
- GNU M4
- GMP
- MPFR
- MPC
- EXPAT
- APR and APR-UTIL
- ISL

but when I try to install locally gcc, after a successfull `configure`, when I try `make` I got this error:

> configure: error: in `/home/aantonietti/gcc/host-powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc':
>
> configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
>
> See `config.log' for more details.
>
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:4333: configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/aantonietti/gcc'
>
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:23745: stage1-bubble] Error 2
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aantonietti/gcc'
>
> make: *** [Makefile:945: all] Error 2

I also tried to install `clang++` but it needs tons of other dependecies.

Do you have any hint on how to install just the `gcc-c++` compiler?

Comment: You need a C++ compiler to compile gcc. You may try with clang pre-built binaries, but I'm not sure if that works. http://releases.llvm.org/download.html

Comment: Ask your sysadmin to install *some* C++ compiler. Then use it (at least to compile a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Otherwise, make a C++ cross compiler on your Linux laptop (that would take you a lot of time) for your PowerPC server.

Comment: *"...  on a IBM Power7 with Fedora 26... "* - That sounds like a GCC compile farm task. If so, check in `/opt/cfarm` for the latest compilers and other build tools. There is also an `/opt/latest` with tools like `emacs`.

Comment: I checked /opt, but it is an empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run `dnf install gcc-c++`?  It will install the C++ system compiler bring in linking support for `libstdc++` as well.

Comment: Because to run dnf you need to be a root user

Comment: Then ask someone who has, or figure out how you can get a chroot/container on the system which has a C++ compiler. The person who gave you access to the machine to do your job certainly does not expect you to build your own C++ compiler just because you can't install the system compiler.